# При передачи с MapView на TableViewCell адреса, адрес передается скобках

Tags: swift

Суть такая пишу учебный проект как обычно у препода на видео все ок у меня нет. Проблема в том, что на MapView когда притаскиваешь пин а адрес, он почему то с в скобках, хотя дополнительных скобок ни где не ставил
Вот что имеем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код :

```
    import UIKit
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation


    protocol MapViewControllerDelegate {
    func getAddress(_ address: String?)
}
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapViewControllerDelegate: MapViewControllerDelegate?
    var place = Place()
    var annatationIndentifier = "annatationIndentifier"
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var distanceOfMethre: Double = 10_000.00
    var incomeSegueIndetifire = ""
    var placeCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapPinImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addressLable.text = ""
        mapView.delegate = self
        setupMapView()
        checkLocationServices()
    }
    
    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed() {
        mapViewControllerDelegate?.getAddress(addressLable.text)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func centerViweInUserLocdtion() {
        showUserLocation()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func goButtonPressed() {
        getDirections()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func closeVC() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    private func setupMapView(){
        
        goButton.isHidden = true
        
        if incomeSegueIndetifire == "showPlace"{
            setupPlaceMark()
            mapPinImage.isHidden = true
            addressLable.isHidden = true
            doneButton.isHidden = true
            goButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    
    
    private func setupPlaceMark(){
        guard let location = place.location else {return}
        
        let geocode = CLGeocoder()
        geocode.geocodeAddressString(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let placemarks = placemarks else { return }
            let placemark = placemarks.first
            let annatation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annatation.title = self.place.name
            annatation.subtitle = self.place.type
            
            guard let placemarkLocation = placemark?.location else {return}
            annatation.coordinate = placemarkLocation.coordinate
            self.placeCoordinate = placemarkLocation.coordinate
            
            self.mapView.showAnnotations([annatation], animated: true)
            self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annatation, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    private func checkLocationServices(){
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAutorization()
        } else{
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.showAlert(title: "Your Location is not Available",
                          message: "To give permission Go to: Setting -> MyPlaces -> Location")
            }
        }
            
    }
    
    private func setupLocationManager(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
    
    private func checkLocationAutorization(){
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            if incomeSegueIndetifire == "getAddress" {showUserLocation()}
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            break
        case .denied:
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.showAlert(title: "Your Location is not Available",
                          message: "To give permission Go to: Setting -> MyPlaces -> Location")
            }
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        @unknown default:
            print("new case is avalible")
        }
    }
    
    private func showUserLocation(){
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate{
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location,
                                            latitudinalMeters: distanceOfMethre,
                                            longitudinalMeters: distanceOfMethre)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    private func getDirections(){
        guard let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate else {showAlert(title: "Error",
                                                                                  message: "Current location is not found")
                                                                                  return}
        guard let request = createDirectionReqest(for: location) else { showAlert(title: "Error",
                                                                                  message: "Distenation is not fount")
                                                                                  return}
        let direction = MKDirections(request: request)
        direction.calculate { (response, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response else { self.showAlert(title: "Error",
                                                                message: "Diretion is not avalible")
                                                                return
            }
            for route in response.routes{
                self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
                self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect , animated: true )
                
                let distance = String(format: "%.1f", route.distance / 1000)
                let timeInterval = route.expectedTravelTime
                
                print("Расстояни в пути \(distance) км")
                print("Время в пути \(timeInterval) сек ")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createDirectionReqest(for coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MKDirections.Request?{
        guard let distanationCoordinate = placeCoordinate else { return nil }
        let startingLocatoin = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
        let destinantion = MKPlacemark(coordinate: distanationCoordinate)
        
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: startingLocatoin)
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinantion)
        request.transportType = .walking
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
        
        return request
    }

    private func getCenterLocation(mapView:MKMapView) -> CLLocation{
        let latitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude
        let longitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude
        return CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
    
    
    private func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
    
    
    

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annatationIndentifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        
        if annotationView == nil{
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annatationIndentifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        }
        
        if let imageData = place.imageData{
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = imageView
            
        }
        return annotationView
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        let center = getCenterLocation(mapView: mapView)
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(center) { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let placemarks = placemarks else {return }
            let placemark = placemarks.first
            let streetName = placemark?.thoroughfare
            let buildNumber = placemark?.subThoroughfare
            
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if streetName != nil && buildNumber != nil {
                    self.addressLable.text = "(\(streetName!), \(buildNumber!))"
                } else if streetName != nil {
                    self.addressLable.text = "(\(streetName!))"
                } else {
                    self.addressLable.text = ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let render = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay as! MKPolyline)
        render.strokeColor = .blue
        return render
    }
}

    extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        checkLocationAutorization()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите лишние скобки,

```
if streetName != nil && buildNumber != nil {
    self.addressLable.text = "(\(streetName!), \(buildNumber!))"
} else if streetName != nil {
    self.addressLable.text = "(\(streetName!))"
}
```

если они не нужны:

```
if streetName != nil && buildNumber != nil {
    self.addressLable.text = "\(streetName!), \(buildNumber!)"
} else if streetName != nil {
    self.addressLable.text = "\(streetName!)"
}
```

Также можно избавиться от force unwrapping:

```
if let streetName = streetName, let buildNumber = buildNumber {
    self.addressLable.text = "\(streetName), \(buildNumber)"
} else if let streetName = streetName {
    self.addressLable.text = "\(streetName)"
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, просто делал как у преподавателя но он видать на старом swift пишет